# EntityFramework mapping fragments issue

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, db-first

I am working on an API web project, in ASP.net, and on the recommendation of several stackoverflow users, with a description of my problem, I have decided to use EntityFramework.

Work on a database already created, and formed, with all relationships. I have already generated all the corresponding entities, and do the first sql, to get a small example ql that will return all the data of a given table.

But when I get the query and execute it, I get the error 3002 with the following description:

> error 3002: Problem in mapping fragments starting at line 12441:Potential runtime violation of table propuestaMarca's keys (propuestaMarca.marca, propuestaMarca.propuesta): Columns (propuestaMarca.propuesta, propuestaMarca.marca) are mapped to EntitySet propuestaMarca's properties (propuestaMarca.propuesta.cod_propuesta, propuestaMarca.marca.cod_marca) on the conceptual side but they do not form the EntitySet's key properties (propuestaMarca.marca.cod_marca, propuestaMarca.propuesta.cod_propuesta, propuestaMarca.propuesta.empresa).

When I review the .emdx model, I see the following:

[image]

The table propuestaMarca does not exist in the model. It is not exported correctly

[image]

When I review the .emdx model, I see the following:

The proposed tableBrand does not exist in the model. It is not exported correctly.

I have searched for information about error 3002, and I have found that removing a certain primary key from one of the two tables solves the problem, and had tried to eliminate the primary Empleado key in the propuesta table, but it has not worked.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This error can also occur when the primary key is made by the combination of more than one attribute (composite key). It looks like you have two "keys" in the propuesta table.

From the error message above:

(**propuestaMarca.propuesta, propuestaMarca.marca**) -> *2 columns*

are mapped to EntitySet propuestaMarca's properties

(**propuestaMarca.propuesta.cod_propuesta, propuestaMarca.marca.cod_marca**) -> *2 columns*

on the conceptual side but they do not form the EntitySet's key properties

(**propuestaMarca.marca.cod_marca, propuestaMarca.propuesta.cod_propuesta, propuestaMarca.propuesta.empresa**). -> *3 columns*

So I think you should check the mapping.

Comment: I see the problem of mapping, which is using cod_propuesta, cod_marca and empresa, and this is done automatically, by generating everything related to the database in the model.

I cannot delete the primary key empresa , it is necessary in the database.

Comment: You can try right clicking the columns of the .emdx and see whether you have any Entity key that should not be checked. 
If everything looks fine, maybe you should Select all tables and delete from Model. Then update model from db and add all the required tables again.

Comment: Hi, my problem was that table was wrong, deleting that table, solved my problem. Thanks.